# excluded directories in find command not properly piped to -exec cp

Tags: find, exec, cp, exclusionpath

I am trying to copy a folder containing a subfolder structure, while excluding a specified subfolder by using the find -exec cp command. I have managed to use multiple working excluding options when I am using the find command alone, but once I add the '-exec cp' command, the excluding terms work no longer.

Imagine the directory of interest containing multiple files and subfolders, with one subfolder named "exclusion_string"

This find command works properly when used alone:

```
find ~/directory/of/interest/ -maxdepth 2 ! -name "*exclusion_string*"
```

... while this command negates the exclusion criterium:

```
find ~/directory/of/interest/ -maxdepth 2 ! -name "*exclusion_string*" -exec cp -r '{}' . \;
```

Likewise, when using other criteria or arguments, the exclusion of a subdirectory is lost, E.g:

```
find ~/directory/of/interest/ -maxdepth 2 -name "*" -size -100k -exec cp -r '{}' . \;

find ~/directory/of/interest/ -maxdepth 2 -name "*exclusion_string*" | xargs cp -rt .
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue, you need a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Maybe the excluded directories are sub-directories of one of the chosen directories? `cp -r` copies recursively

Comment: That is indeed the case; I would like to copy a folder along with its sub-directory structure while excluding one subdirectory. How can I keep the directory structure without copying recursively?

Comment: This would be easier with `rsync` instead of `cp`, it supports exclusion patterns as well